# Do introduction points know their hidden services' onion addresses?

Tags: darknet

If that's the case, how come law enforcement is not forcing them to close their connections with illegal hidden services?

Answer (score 1):

Hidden services anonymously choose random Tor relays as introduction points. The introduction points do not know the service location of the hidden service and can't control which hidden service they act as introduction points.

[image]

Source: https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/overview/

---

Due to this, law enforcement can't just shutdown these connections because there will always be other Tor relays to act as introductions points. They would have to shutdown the entire Tor network if they wanted to which they can't because they themselves use the Tor network.

Comment: How does an Introduction point send data to a hidden service if it doesn't know it's .onion address ?

Comment: @AzertyPoit That was a mistake - I meant service location not address.

Answer (score 0):

By default they can **not** know anything about the party connecting to them, so no law enforcement can be applied, *but* if the introduction point is running some additional software - it can determine what is behind the connection *sometimes*. So you don't have to worry